# How to pass data from model to another dart file and use them as variable?

Tags: flutter

I want to pass data from model to home_screen.dart file. And use them as variable for my box.

model.dart

```
class DataModel {
  String buttonLetter;
  int buttonHeight;
  int buttonWidth;
  int buttonStartingXpoint;
  int buttonStartingYpoint;

  DataModel(
      {required this.buttonLetter,
      required this.buttonHeight,
      required this.buttonWidth,
      required this.buttonStartingXpoint,
      required this.buttonStartingYpoint});



  DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    buttonLetter = json['Button_letter'] ?? json['Button_letter'],
    buttonHeight = json['Button_height'] ?? json['Button_height'],
    buttonWidth = json['Button_width'] ?? json['Button_width'],
    buttonStartingXpoint = json['Button_Starting_xpoint'] ?? json['Button_Starting_xpoint'],
    buttonStartingYpoint = json['Button_Starting_ypoint'] ?? json['Button_Starting_ypoint'];
  

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Button_letter'] = this.buttonLetter;
    data['Button_height'] = this.buttonHeight;
    data['Button_width'] = this.buttonWidth;
    data['Button_Starting_xpoint'] = this.buttonStartingXpoint;
    data['Button_Starting_ypoint'] = this.buttonStartingYpoint;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I want to use this variable --buttonLetter to buttonStartingYpoint-- in my home_screen.dart file

home_screen.dart

```
import 'data_model.dart';


class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() =>_HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<Homescreen>{
  String text = 'Login';

  List<DataModel> ? model;

  @override
  void initState(){
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Project'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: SizedBox(
  
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: Text(text),
)
,
),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use button letter on text field, and button height and width on box width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass DataModel via Constructor
And use it in your widget
your home screen :

```
class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget{
  final DataModel dataModel;

  const Homescreen({Key? key, required this.dataModel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() =>_HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<Homescreen>{
  String text = 'Login';

  List<DataModel> ? model;

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Project'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: SizedBox(

        width: double.parse(widget.dataModel.buttonWidth.toString()),
        height: double.parse(widget.dataModel.buttonHeight.toString()),
        child: Text(widget.dataModel.buttonLetter),
      )
        ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is how to call it :

```
 Homescreen(
        dataModel: DataModel(
            buttonLetter: 'button Letter',
            buttonHeight: 100, //this should be double not int 
            buttonWidth: 100, //this should be double not int 
            buttonStartingXpoint: 100,
            buttonStartingYpoint: 100),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It didn't totally solved my code. but I got ideas . Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help ❤️ you can also use state management packages like provider or getx this will make it easier and faster